# Why is viewport unresponsive for several seconds except when changing angles for viewing?

Tags: 3d-view, geometry-nodes, vertices, faces, frame-rate

I have been following the [NENGHUO Betta Fish YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3R8f98n3ss) to get the fins effect he has and the animation curve which is based on the [Cartesian Caramel Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvHLQGUo-y4).

[image]

I have only finished the 1st video of the NENGHUO video and now the Blender viewport takes twenty seconds to do anything with the model except changing angles for viewing it in the viewport. I don't know if this is caused by too many faces/vertices or if it's something else in Geometry Nodes.

These are my computer stats and I feel like it should work:

> Processor AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX with Radeon Graphics           3.30 GHz
> Installed RAM 64.0 GB (63.4 GB usable) System type    64-bit operating
> system, x64-based processor Pen and touch

I know the frame rate drop/change time is because of the fins, but I don't know what in the fins is causing it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but no one here is likely to have seen or heard of the tutorials you're talking about. You should add images or some links to your question so that we can understand your problem. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: Hi, Eli, welcome.. If you can't tell what the problem is, sitting at your machine, with your own  workspace in front of you, it's _very_ unlikely that any of us can, with nothing at all in front of us. Please present a  minimal, self-contained, version of your problem, containing all the information you think a complete stranger to your project would need, to help you. Include at least an illustration of your mesh wireframe. You can share a version of your file manifesting the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Yeah, sorry here you go, anyone who wants to answer.